# Parsing the req.body from a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, body-parser

I have created an app using Node.js, Express, Body-parser, and Handlebars. I am currently in a hypothetical situation where I have dynamically created x number of buttons based on x number of entries in a database.

This is how the buttons are created

```
<form method="POST" action="/favoriteCreator">
    <input type="submit" name="{{this.id}}" value="{{this.fname}} {{this.lname}}">
</form>
```

And this is what I do when I POST to the server

```
app.post('/favoriteCreator', function(req, res) {
    var button = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

When I get the req.body it gives me back the correct information (The button name of 'this.id', and the button value of 'first name and last name'. The syntax is this:

```
{ '1': 'Tom Bradstreet' }
{ whatever id is: whatever firstname lastname is }
```

So I am getting the body, the problem is I don't know how to parse to get only the ID. When I try to do req.body.name I get undefined because well obviously .name would be referring to the actual string. So I'm having a problem getting the first element out of the request body since the name of each button is dynamically created. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.keys(req.body);` or use a `for...of` if just iterating without needing the keys.

Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
let keys = Object.keys(req.body);
console.log(req.body[keys[0]]);
```

or here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

```
for(let item of req.body){
   console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for that, I didn't even know about the mozilla docs tbh. I was looking for the creator ID so i just did console.log(keys) instead of req.body(keys[0]) and it gave me the correct output. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Glad to help. It is customary to upvote and accept the answer. I realize you don't have the credit to upvote, but please do accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I also upvoted your question. It was well written and directed me to the answer immediately. We don't see that often from new visitors - so **Thanks back at ya!**

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, the answer by Randy is right. In my case I wanted to get the key but key[0] would return Tom Bradstreet intead of 1. What I had to do was,

```
    app.post('/favoriteCreator', function(req, res) {
    var keys = Object.keys(req.body);
    console.log(keys.toString());
});
```

if you do console.log(keys) it will give you an unusable array. In my case I got [ '1' ]. So I had to convert it using toString() to get 1. I'm not sure how safe toString() actually is in this case, but it is how I got to a usability state.

Answer (score 0):

won't this work?

```
<form method="POST" action="/favoriteCreator/{{this.id}}">
    <input type="submit" name="{{this.id}}" value="{{this.fname}} {{this.lname}}">
</form>
```

then,

```
app.post('/favoriteCreator/:id', function(req, res) {
    var button = req.body;
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

Actually I am new to these and neglect me if this is wrong.